# Upper bound for runtime complexity of LOOP programs

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, upper-bound

Recently I learned about [LOOP programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOP_(programming_language)), which always terminate and have the same computational power as primitive recursive functions.
Furthermore primitve recursive functions can (as far as I understood) compute anything that isn't growing faster than $Ack(n)$.

Is this implying that the upper bound runtime complexity for LOOP programs is $O(Ack(n))$? And are there functions similar to Ackermann's function, which can't be computed by primitive recursive functions, but grow slower than $Ack(n)$?

(sorry for spelling and grammar)

Answer (score 1):

The Ackermann function is a two-argument function:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}A(0,n) & = & n + 1 \\ A(m,0) & = & A(m-1,1) \\ A(m,n) & = & A(m-1,A(m,n-1))\end{eqnarray*}$$

Ackermann's function is an example of a function that isn't primitive recursive, but that doesn't by itself mean that the bound is tight.

It has the following properties:

1. The family of functions $\mathrm{Ack'}_m(n) = A(m,n)$ are all primitive recursive. You can trivially see this by fixing $m$ and expanding the definition of $A$.
2. If $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a primitive recursive function, then there exists some integer $n$ such that $f(i) < A(n,i)$ for all $i \ge n$. This result is not immediately obvious, but it's in most textbooks on the topic.

Note that from property 2, it follows that $\mathrm{Ack}(n) = A(n,n)$ is not primitive recursive.

These two properties taken together mean that Ackermann's function does, in some sense, give you a tight bound on the time complexity of primitive recursive functions. Intuitively, of all primitive recursive functions, $\mathrm{Ack}'_m$ grow the "fastest".

So a function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is primitive recursive if and only if there is a natural number $m$ such that $f(n)$ can be computed by a Turing machine that always halts within $A(m,n)$ or fewer steps. This can be fairly easily extended to primitive recursive functions of multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Take Ack(n-1). Grows much slower than Ack(n).